# Hooks to install files outside of /opt/ros in Debian packages?

Tags: ros, debian, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a driver package that requires adding udev rules to ensure the system device files have proper permissions. Rather than having some manual step(s) documented, I'd like to have the ROS package just install the required file.

Are there any hooks that are available to have the ROS build farm add install rules for files outside of the /opt/ros hierarchy? Specifically I'd like to install a file in /etc/udev/rules.d/

I've notice that packages put docs in /usr/share/doc/ros--/changelog.Debian.gz, but I don't see what rule added the change log to this location.

Also, is there any support for [maintainer scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#maintscripts)? Future drivers may require building loadable kernel modules and I was hoping to use the postinst maintainer script to run [DKMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) to build the required modules if the kernel is not already patched.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239969/hooks-to-install-files-outside-of-/opt/ros-in-debian-packages?/) by [mdhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/27278/mdhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-07-22**:
Maybe check the [Debian packages](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Robotics/ROS) (from Debian repos).they don't use /opt at all. E.g package python-gencpp contains /etc/ros/genmsg/gencpp.

**Comment by [mdhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/27278/mdhorn/) on 2016-07-22**:
I could manually create rules to accomplish my goal, but I wondering if there are hooks available so that I can have a package built in the ROS build farm implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general it's a bad idea to do this, because then packages from two different ROS distributions will be installing conflicting files. For example, if you release your package for both Indigo and Jade, then the binary deb's for your packages on those distributions will not be installable at the same time, which defeats the whole point of having things installed to `/opt/ros/<distro>`.

You can use a debian hook if you want. If there is a `debian` folder in a package, then bloom will leave the files there and only add the rules, control, etc files. See:

- https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/commit/1ac0f59fa5c0f163f2a36d1f3df5a8adc6701a8a
- https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/146

For example, the pointgrey camera driver package installs udev rules:

- https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/tree/master/pointgrey_camera_driver/debian

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mdhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/27278/mdhorn/) on 2016-07-25**:
This exactly what I need to know. Thank you.